# Python command error passed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

hello i trying to add `{0.subcommand_passed}` in `await bot.send_message` but i getting error so how to add to catch wrong command passed in reply.

So if members type `?helol` rather than `?hello`, Bot should reply `helol is a wrong command`

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "**Wrong command ** " + ctx.invoked_with)
```

and in Subcommand if members type `?cool girl` rather than `?cool boy`, Bot should reply `girl is a wrong sub command`

```
@bot.group(pass_context=True)
async def cool(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        if ctx.subcommand_passed:
            await bot.say("**Wrong sub command: **{}".format(ctx.subcommand_passed))
        else:
            await bot.say("**Subcommand required**. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message))

@cool.command(pass_context=True)
async def boy(ctx):
    msg = "Hello ...".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Context.subcommand_passed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.subcommand_passed) to get the text of an attempted subcommand.

```
@bot.group(pass_context=True)
async def cool(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        if ctx.subcommand_passed:
            await bot.say("**Wrong sub command: **{}".format(ctx.subcommand_passed))
        else:
            await bot.say("Subcommand required")

@cool.command(pass_context=True, name="bot")
async def _bot(ctx):
    msg = "Hello ...".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

An unrecognized top-level command will raise [`CommandNotFound`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandNotFound), which you'll have to handle in `on_command_error`.  I believe it should still populate [`ctx.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.command) with the attempted command, but I can't check at the moment.  You might also try [`ctx.invoked_with`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.command)

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "**Wrong command ** " + ctx.command)
```

Comment: got error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Bot.py", line 31, in <module>
    bot.run(token)
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'run'
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0276BC70>`

Comment: That's because on of your commands is named `bot`.  We can change the name of the object pretty easily.

Comment: I getting error in `on_command_error`  like this `in on_command_error
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "**Wrong command ** " + ctx.command)
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`

Comment: Did you try with `ctx.invoked_with`?

Comment: yes worked with  `ctx.invoked_with` i updated my code above but my original command `await bot.say` mentioned author now its not tagging user.

Comment: Just add those back in.

Comment: yes tried everything worked exept for this `await bot.say("**Wrong sub command: **{}".format(ctx.subcommand_passed))`

Comment: What do you expect that to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: Its working but i tried `{0.author.mention}` to add  `await bot.say("**Wrong sub command: **{}, {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.subcommand_passed))` it not worked

Comment: Did you alter the format string to have a field for the author? `"{0.message.author.mention}, {0.subcommand_passed} is not a subcommand".format(ctx)`